# R combining FF base and Sqldf

Tags: r, sqlite, csv, bigdata

Up until this point I've been using a combination of Sqldf and R functions to manage my datasets. However, I need to do a bunch of left-joins on large datasets and I start to run out of memory even using sqldf dbname=tempfile().

The first thing I noticed with FF is that I cannot pass it to sqldf. The second thing I noticed is that my typical functions do not all work in ff.

Example of my normal joining

```
base <- read.csv(filename)
base <- sqldf("select * from base where DATE > 20120101")

for (j in list.files()){
   temp <- read.csv(tempfile)
   temp <- sqldf("select MATCH_KEY, DATE from temp")
   base <- sqldf("select * from base NATURAL LEFT OUTER JOIN temp")
 }
```

with ffbase I could not simply use "as.ffdf(temp)." The work around was to write a physical temp file, then read it in as ff, then do a merge with ff-s. I feel this is not such a great way to work with ff. Any better alternatives?

The second problem I'm facing is probably due to how unfamiliar I am with ff. I have a simple code I just don't know how to implement in ff. Basically I have the data frame base, which I want to loop over and count the number of times the value is greater than a certain number. An idea using my dates example (in reality I'm also checking numbers, ratios, etc, but the idea is always the same).

```
checks <- c(20010101,20020101,20030101)
summary <- matrix(0,ncol=dim(base)[2],nrow=length(checks))

for (i in checks){
  for (j in dim(base)[2]){
     summary[i,j]<-sum(base[,j]>=i)
}}
```

These functions wouldn't work with ff either. Right now I am in fact reading in the files using sqldf, then writing to a temporary file. Reading those in with ff, then doing all the merging business. Then, I'm once again writing out to a temporary file, and reading it back in as a normal file. Ouf! Any advice on improvements?

[EDIT]

A big question is, how to convert a table created via sqldf (temp <-sqldf(stuff)) using as.ffdf. I'm getting an error : "Error in ff(initdata = initdata, length = length, levels = levels, ordered = ordered, : vmode 'character' not implemented"

Also, two examples of functions I can't seem to get working in ff.

1) I often replace missing values in a file with 0 to distinguish them with missings created from a merge. I do this by

```
   DF[is.na(DF)] <- 0
```

with ff it seems a bit more involved, and I worry about losing readability: [Replace NAs in a ffdf object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13510838/replace-nas-in-a-ffdf-object)

2) Taking the sum over a column or row, looking for specific values. Example, count the number of times "R" appears in a column. In ff?

Comment: for your first question , `as.ffdf(temp)` should work. What do you get as error?

Comment: For the second question, you should give a your "base" table, what have you tried in `ff` (what error do you get)

Comment: when using as.ffdf, the error said something about character vmodes. For the second question, most of my calculations are using combinations of ifelse and sums over rows. The sums over rows haven't worked in ff. sum(ff[,rowNum]>=5) --> not valid

Comment: Try this:  `BODff <- as.ffdf(BOD); class(BODff) <- c("ffdf"
, "data.frame"); sqldf("select * from BODff", method = "raw")`  . Note that the sqldf statement will return a data frame so if you want an ff object you will have to convert it using `as.ffdf`.  Also `method = "raw"` is needed but does mean that it will not do certain automatic conversions which `sqldf` normally does.

Comment: SQL sees the ffdf after changing the class, even without specifying the method. Thanks! But, why?

Comment: However, if I get a table using sqldf (in the example above temp), then I can't easily convert using as.ffdf. I get : "Error in ff(initdata = initdata, length = length, levels = levels, ordered = ordered,  :   vmode 'character' not implemented"

Comment: characters ff vectors are currently not supported in ff. You need to convert you character columns to factors. As in x <- sqldf("yourquery", stringsAsFactors = TRUE); x <- as.ffdf(x). See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17251064/convert-data-frame-to-ff

Comment: This doesn't convert all characters to factors, leaving me with the same error. To get around the issue, I went with: ind <- sapply(test, is.character); test[ind] <- lapply(test[ind], factor). Still however, not sure to do the other simple calculations on an ff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question. Why don't you do this?

```
require(ffbase)
base <- read.csv.ffdf(filename)
open(base)
base <- subset(base, DATE > 20120101)

for (j in list.files()){
  temp <- read.csv.ffdf(tempfile, transFUN=function(x){
    x[c("MATCH_KEY","DATE")]
  })
  base <- merge(base, temp, by.x="MATCH_KEY", by.y="MATCH_KEY", all.x=TRUE)
}
```

To make sqldf work with ffdf objects, there might be some changes needed in sqldf namely at the point where it pushes data from the ffdf to sqlite, this needs to be done in chunks so that it will not overblow RAM. Also extraction back into R in an ffdf should be handled differently in sqldf (maybe by using read.dbi.ffdf from ETLUtils) - maybe ask this to the sqldf package author as a change request.

Regarding your second question, do show what you have tried with ff and where you stopped trying further. Because what you pinpoint in your question is perfectly possible with ff.

Comment: I avoid read.csv.ffdf because you can't specify a seperator. (can you?) I have files with different seperators depending on the filetype ";" for one and "^" for others, etc.

Comment: Use read.table.ffdf then if you need to specify the separator and the file is not strictly a csv.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! In france, CSV implies separated by ";", and it's the default option for excel. I tend to receive a lot of files with strange separators.