# na.locf() for an FFDF

Tags: r

I have a very large data set that I have to use as an `ffdf`, and am stuck trying to fill `NA` values using a last observation carried forward operation. Below is a sample of what the data looks like I'm trying to do the operation on:

```
require("zoo")
require("ff")
ID <- c(1:21)
start <- c(11288475000, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
           11299487500, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
           12398646000, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA))
frame <- data.frame(ID, start)
frame.ffdf <- as.ffdf(frame)
```

With a regular data frame this is an easy operation using the `zoo` package:

```
frame$start <- na.locf(frame$start)
```

however the same will not work on the `ffdf`:

```
>frame.ffdf$start <- na.locf(frame.ffdf$start)
Error in which(L) : argument to 'which' is not logical
```

I tried using `within()` as this usually solves any problems I have when using an `ffdf`, but it threw the error:

```
>frame.ffdf$start <- within(frame.ffdf,
                            na.locf(start))
Error in `[[<-.ffdf`(`*tmp*`, i, value = list(virtual = list(VirtualVmode = c("integer",  : 
  assigned value must be ff
```

So I tried the following, which threw the following error:

```
>frame.ffdf$start <- ff(within(frame.ffdf,
                        na.locf(start)))
Error in ff(within(frame.ffdf, na.locf(start))) : 
  initdata[1] must be atomic
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13510838/replace-nas-in-a-ffdf-object) question about replacing `NA` values with another set value, but haven't been able to find one using a `na.locf()` type function. I know I can accomplish this with a `for` loop, but it will take entirely too long due to the size of my data sets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know anything about ffdf, but it seems that the `$` doesn't work exactly the same way as in `data.frame`, but the column operators do:

```
library(ff)#you should include this in your example, I had to google the library
library(zoo)
na.locf(frame$start)#this works
na.locf(frame.ffdf$start)#this doesn't
na.locf(frame.ffdf[,2])#this does (why?)
na.locf(frame.ffdf[,'start'])#this does (why?)
frame.ffdf[,2] = na.locf(frame.ffdf[,2])#whatever, take what you can get
```

So yeah, I'm not sure why it works, but if you use column operators instead of `$` operators you should be fine.

Comment: Column operators...the one thing I didn't try and didn't because there's a lot of columns in my set so I just kept trying `$`, but counting them will work just fine. Like you said, take what you can get; works like a charm, many thanks. I'll edit to include the package in case someone comes a long that can offer any insight as to why it works.